# jQuery Using $.map/$.each to update every third column of every row with $.post results calculated from first column of each row of the table in Yii

Tags: ajax

I am trying to update the every third column of every row using data calculated from the first column of every row in an ajax call. I couldn't get the $.map or $.each line to update every third column of every row with the data generated from the $.post request.

```
var relationsToSeller = [];

$('tr td:first-child').find('a').each(function(index, value) { 
    var portfolioArray = $(this).attr('href').split('&id=');

    //Ajax request to get username's relation to seller and append text 
    $.post( 'http://localhost/public/?r=matchTable/relationtoseller', { portfolioId: portfolioArray[1] })
      .done(function( data ) {


        //$('tr td').first().text(data);
        var relationToSeller = data;
        relationsToSeller.push(relationToSeller);
        //console.log(relationsToSeller);


        // Therefore, convert it to a real array
        var realArray = $.makeArray( relationsToSeller )

        // Now it can be used reliably with $.map()
        $.map( realArray, function( val, i ) {
          // Do something
          $('tr:eq(i) td:eq(2)').text(val);
        });


        //$.each(relationsToSeller, function( index, value ) {
            //var pop = relationsToSeller.pop();
            //console.log(relationsToSeller);
          //console.log( index + ': ' + value );
         // console.log($( 'tr:eq( index ) td:eq( 2 )' ).text( value ));
          //$( 'tr:eq( 5 ) td:eq( 2 )' ).text(value);
            //$('tr:eq(index) td:eq(2)').text(value);
        //});

    });

});
```

Comment: `'tr:eq(i) td:eq(2)'` you do realize `i` is in the middle of a string, right? so it won't actually replace `i` with the index?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working and do what I want with this code:

```
var relationsToSeller = [];

$('tr td:first-child').find('a').each(function(index, value) { 
    var portfolioArray = $(this).attr('href').split('&id=');

    //Ajax request to get username's relation to seller and append text 

    $(this).parent().next().next().find('a').load( 'http://localhost/public/?r=matchTable/relationtoseller', { portfolioId: portfolioArray[1] });

});
```